# GatsbyJS: Change menu link when switching between pages

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple Gatsby site using two languages. In the header component, there is a link to the second language, when clicking on it, that language becomes the selected one and the other must appear as an option. Everything works but does not load these changes without refreshing the page. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"
import Logo from "../images/logo.svg"

const path = window.location.pathname;

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="nav-links">
            <Link to="/" className="logo">
              <Logo />
            </Link>
            <div className="wrapper">
              <AnchorLink href="#contact" className="nav-item contact">
                Contact us
              </AnchorLink>
            </div>
            <AnchorLink className="button button--sm" href="#contact">
              Contact
            </AnchorLink>
            {path === '/' && (
              <Link to='/de' className="nav-item">
                DE
              </Link>
            )}
            {path === '/de' && (
              <Link to='/' className="nav-item">
                EN
              </Link>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should put the `path` variable inside the `Header` component so that it is re-evaluated on each render.

```
const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  return ( 
    <>
      <header>
```

Comment: Really, that was it! Thanks a lot!